# Sending a File to Node.js retrieve an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, node.js

I am currently investigating a problem with my node.js app.
Basicly I want to send a file using form data (which works fine) then parse the file and create an array which contents the files data and then send it back to the client.
Here is a sample:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="/upload" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type='file' name='fileInput' />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="subFile">
    </form>
```

from my .ejs template.

I ajax the form data vis javascript:

```
document.getElementById('uploadForm').onsubmit = function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function (data) {

            var map = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("data");
            for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
                console.log("asdasdasd" + map[i]);
            }

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

On server side, I create an array containing following objects:

```
var objects =
    {
        item1: 0,
        item2: "",
        additional: []
    };
```

And I simply push data to the objects.additional and then push the objects to the array.

Now I want to send it back to the client, to update anything with the data.

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(map));
```

I am getting these errors:

"
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data  ajax.js:18:27
    .success localhost:1337/js/ajax.js:18:27
    ._Deferred/e.resolveWith ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js:2:15710
    w ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js:4:8977
    .send/d ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js:4:14788
"

and

"not well-formed" - pointing to upload:1:1

Comment: give more of your server side code.. What is map?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error with the map variable. maybe it's not a well formed object.

you can use a webapp to check if the Object its a correct JSON like
http://jsonlint.com/

can you put an example of the map object?